# How can I download file instead of view in Google cloud storage using html

Tags: html, google-cloud-storage

I want to download files instead of view in Google cloud storage using HTML.

```
<a
  href="https://storage.googleapis.com/test/test.pdf"
  download
  >download</a
```

I'm not able to download the pdf. It's open in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the [Metadata content-type](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata) of your file to `application/octet-stream`.

```
gsutil -h "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
       gs://test/test.pdf
```

Like this, the browser won't be able to detect the file type and to open the PDF Viewer. So, the browser will propose you to save it on your computer.

*Note: if there is a way to do a similar thing in HTML, it could be good. But I don't know, I'm not good in frontend dev*